# Changing location hash, onhashchange and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, html

When running the following script in Safari and Firefox 5 (other browsers not tested), the memory usage of both browsers increase drastically. But after the function finished, the memory usage still keeps being very high. Safaris memory usage grows by ~80MB, FF up to 200MB.

Any thoughts why, even after some minutes, the memory usage does not decrease?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onhashchange = function() {
        var i = 1; // do something
      };

      function leakIt() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
          window.location.hash = i%4; // Trigger onhashchange
        }
      };

      window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('leak').addEventListener('click', leakIt,false);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="leak">Leak it!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Additional information**

If I reload the page in Safari and call the `leakIt` function again, the memory increases by about 20MB and after `leakIt` terminates, the memory usage goes back to the amount after the first call to `leakIt`.

Comment: There are only two registered event listeners. The one for the `onhashchange` event and the other for the click on the button (which you could remove and call `leakIt` from the console, would not do any difference). So I'm wondering what the browsers are storing, because the only thing I'm doing in the `onhashchange` callback is setting a test variable.

Comment: Oh, I misread the code, sorry. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happend when you refresh the page? While you keep refreshing page and the memory keep increasing,That is memory leak.You can use [Sieve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/) to detect that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm on OS X and I think the tool is IE specific.

If I refresh the page and call the `leakIt` function again, the memory usage increases about 20MB but then goes back to about the amount after the first call to `leakIt`.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, to close the question for now.